# Filtering issues without certain tag on GitHub

Tags: search, github

Does the current GitHub issue search engine provide any way for users to search for reports without certain tag?

Classical use-case would be having a granular grouping such as [bug], [enhancement], [feature] etc. I'd like to search for all items without the [bug] tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd be happy to be proven wrong and delete my answer... but I think at the moment the answer is **no**. Not even the [API](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/) for github Issues seems to allow this.

For your example, I think your best bet is to search for all labels *except* [bug]; or create a new label "non-bug". :)

You can of course [contact github](https://github.com/contact) and put this "filter-out" feature in their suggestion box.

Answer (score 19):

You can exclude search results on GitHub using a minus sign. So to search for all issues not labelled as bugs, you could put the following into a search:

```
type:issue -label:bug
```

[Source](https://help.github.com/articles/search-syntax#filtering-using-exclusion).

Comment: This is quite nice, though it does not offer the same view as filtering by labels directly.

Comment: This is true, I've found it also doesn't seem to work for excluding multiple labels, so: `type:issue -label:bug -label:enhancement` does not return the results I would expect.